# String replace diacritics in C# with equivalent and accents

Tags: c#, normalization

I want to replace the diacritics digits with equivalent value and accents, so:

á, ă, â ... with a'

í, ì, ĭ, î, ǐ, ï, ḯ ... with i'

ú, ü ... with u'

And so on.

I am tring to use this code:

```
var testo = "à, è, ì, ò, ù, À, È, Ì, Ò, Ù";
var testo2 = testo.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
```

but it doesn't work correctly.

Example: Hòw arè yoù? -> Need to become -> Ho'w are' you'?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking for a custom replacement, not normalization. Why should accented `a` characters map to `a'` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is the underlying representation that changes, you can use `toCharArray()` to see there is a difference.

```
var testo = "à, è, ì, ò, ù, À, È, Ì, Ò, Ù";
var testoChars = testo.ToCharArray();
var testoNormChars = testo.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(testoChars.Length);
Console.WriteLine(testoNormChars.Length);
```